# Disable JhiAlertService from using TranslateService to translate message

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

When i use my service to print a message, the JhiAlertService tries to translate the message, how can i disable?

[image]

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageServiceService {
    

    constructor(public translate: TranslateService, public alertService: JhiAlertService) {
        this.getTranslations();
    }
 
 getTranslations(){
  this.clientError1 = this.translate.instant('global.error.clientError1');
  this.clientError2 = this.translate.instant('global.error.clientError2');
 }

    printError(name, clientnumber) {
        this.alertService.error(
            this.clientError1 + name + this.clientError2 + clientnumber 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this issue at their github repo: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7843

Comment: In that issue exist a problem to translate the message,  my issue is to deactivate JhiAlertService from trying  to translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found a way to not activate the translate;

however, to solve the problem it is sufficient to pass the variables between the parameters as follows:

String:

```
MSG_STR: "Hello {{user}}"
```

Alert command:

```
this.alertService.error(MSG_STR, {user: 'Max'}));
```

Result:

```
Hello Max
```

Comment: And `MSG_STR: "{{msg}}"` workarounds translation. :)